# The group $\langle a,b | ab=b^2a^2\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Do you know a name for the group presented in the title, a family where it belongs or any lead that can help me look for it in the literature?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but is there anything in particular you would like to know about this group?

Comment: @DerekHolt Not really. I was trying to find a counterexample (finding a group $G$ with two subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $HK=G$, but with both $H$ and $K$ non-normal; here $H$ and $K$ are the subgroups generated by $a$ and $b$ resp.) and this was the first I could construct. The group looks interesting so I wanted to know if someone had studied it previously.

Comment: This example doesn't work because $ba \not\in HK$. An example is $G=S_4$ with $H$ and $K$ Sylow $2$- and Sylow $3$-subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're absolutely right. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You can amuse yourself adding relators of the form $a^m$ and $b^n$, so $a^3$ ("b^0") gives you $SL(2,3)$, $a^3$; $b^3$: $A4$, $a^5$, $b^5$ : $C11:C5$:, $a^7$,$b^7$:"C29:C7" etc...